# Merge a png overlay and image into single file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got it working using crop as recommended. Here is how I got it with the plugin. The if statement is only because I have multiple crop sizes, the circular crop is only for square images.

```
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);

                if (width==height){
                    context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-in';
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(width/2,height/2,height/2,0,Math.PI*2);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fill();
                }

                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                return imageData;

            },
```

-- Original Question --

I'm using a jQuery plugin called CropBox which I have set up to export a 300x300 image. I am trying to take the square image and add an overlay that will make the image appear round, adding white corners or subtracting the overlay and have transparent corners.

[What I'm going for.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0i04nb499avssv/overlay-example.png?dl=0)

The plugin uses a portion of the canvas to create the image. Once the image is captured I'm looking to add the overlay.

Adding my image and trying to draw the image.

```
var overlay = new Image();
overlay.src = 'MyOverlay.png';

context.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0);
```

Then I get lost on how to add this to imageData. It should start at 0, 0 too, any input would be appreciated.

Part of the plugin:

```
(function ($) {
var cropbox = function(options, el){
    var el = el || $(options.imageBox),
        obj =
        {
            state : {},
            ratio : 1,
            options : options,
            imageBox : el,
            thumbBox : el.find(options.thumbBox),
            spinner : el.find(options.spinner),
            image : new Image(),
            getDataURL: function ()
            {
                var width = this.thumbBox.width(),
                    height = this.thumbBox.height(),
                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                    dim = el.css('background-position').split(' '),
                    size = el.css('background-size').split(' '),
                    dx = parseInt(dim[0]) - el.width()/2 + width/2,
                    dy = parseInt(dim[1]) - el.height()/2 + height/2,
                    dw = parseInt(size[0]),
                    dh = parseInt(size[1]),
                    sh = parseInt(this.image.height),
                    sw = parseInt(this.image.width);

                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                return imageData;
            },
            getBlob: function()
            {
                var imageData = this.getDataURL();
                var b64 = imageData.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
                var binary = atob(b64);
                var array = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
                }
                return  new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
            },
```

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from your example, but you may be able to get away with just a circular "crop", rather than an overlay. If that is the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349877/circular-crop-for-html-canvas

Comment: Awesome thanks! Got it working with the crop, much better route.