# Add image on top of canvas on a certain position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, canvas

So I am trying to rebuild [this site](https://dub.sh/websiteiwanttoreplicate)

I am using React (same as the given site) and the same cropper tool they are using. I use `react-image-crop` for cropping

> There is a lot of code so I just added the things that need to be added

This is my code so far

The JSX

```
<canvas
  ref={canvasRef}
  width={1800}
  height={1800}
  style={{
    backgroundImage: 'url("https://bizexpo.localvocalbusiness.com:8443/images/stallimage/1672025924668.jpg")',
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center center",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
/>
```

The JS logic

```js
async function onImageUpload(files) {
  setOpen(true);
  const [file] = files;
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  setImageUrl(url);
  const ctx = canvasRef.current?.getContext("2d");
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = url;
  image.onload = () => {
    // I have no idea what to do here 
  };
}
```

I tried many ways to replicate the same thing they do, by drawing the image on the canvas. Spent a whole night on this. Read many articles, and saw many videos but I am unable to do the same in my version.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know co-ordinates of that circle in the background where selected image will be placed. Try using the following:

```
function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const contextRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    contextRef.current = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }, [canvasRef]);

  // ...
}
```

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

image.onload = () => {
  contextRef.current.beginPath();

  // Worked fine for size 1800*1800 present in the question
  const radius = 322;
  const marginLeft = 420;
  const marginTop = 860;

  contextRef.current.arc(
    marginLeft,
    marginTop,
    radius,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );

  contextRef.current.clip();

  contextRef.current.drawImage(
    image,
    marginLeft - radius,
    marginTop - radius,
    radius * 2,
    radius * 2
  );
};
```

Checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) for more information about [`arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) and [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

Comment: Thank you so much! That works so well. I still got one problem tho, if the user selects a non-square image, that kind of stretches out.  I somehow solved it sometime ago but I don't remember how https://imgur.com/a/AY3TJl3

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349877/circular-crop-for-html-canvas)?

Comment: If that does not work, can you please post a new question with the relevant debugging details from your component?

Comment: I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020569/drawing-image-on-canvas-stretches-out-the-images

Comment: Fixed it. It was a problem with the cropper.